# Make References like Visual Studio in CMake

Tags: cmake

I start to use CMake recently and I starting to get used to the program. I managed to generate two Visual Studio solutions/projects: a shared library (core.dll) and a static library (zlib.lib). Now I still have a problem, my core.dll library makes references to the zlib library in Visual Studio. (In Properties -> Common Properties -> References). How can I reproduce this?

Here is how my files are located:

project 
---core 
------src 
------CMakeLists.txt 
---external 
------zlib 
------CMakeLists.txt 
---------zlib-1.2.8

And here my two CMakeLists :

For core.dll

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#Configuration project

project(core CXX)

#add definitions
#set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH_DEBUG vc2013_x64/bin/)
set(BIN_PATH "../vc2013_x64d")
set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/bin/" )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/bin/" )
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/bin/" )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4")
add_definitions(-D_UNICODE -D_USRDLL -DCORE_EXPORTS)
add_definitions("/Gm")#"/GL" "/Gy" 

#remove_definitions
add_definitions(-UCMAKE_INTDIR="Release")
#Configuration Library
add_library(

        core

        SHARED

    ... .h and .cpp 
)
```

For zlib.lib

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

#Configuration de ZLib

PROJECT(zlib C)

SET(BIN_PATH "../core/vc2013_x64d")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/lib/" )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/lib/" )
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/lib/" )
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W3")
ADD_DEFINITIONS("/Gm" -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_UNICODE)


ADD_LIBRARY(

    zlib

    STATIC

    ... .h and .c

)
```

**EDIT :** 
It's work like this :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#Configuration de Zlib.lib

PROJECT(zlib C)

SET(BIN_PATH "../cmakex64d")
#SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/lib/" )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/lib/" )
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/lib/" )
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W3")
ADD_DEFINITIONS("/Gm" -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_UNICODE)


ADD_LIBRARY(

    zlib

    STATIC

    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/adler32.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/compress.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/crc32.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/deflate.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/gzclose.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/gzlib.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/gzread.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/gzwrite.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/infback.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/inffast.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/inflate.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/inftrees.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/trees.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/uncompr.c
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/zutil.c

    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/crc32.h
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/deflate.h
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/gzguts.h
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/inffast.h
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/inffixed.h
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/inflate.h
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/inftrees.h
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/trees.h
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/zlib.h
    external/zlib/zlib-1.2.8/zutil.h

)

project(core CXX)

set(BIN_PATH "../cmakex64d")
set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/bin/" )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/bin/" )
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_PATH}/bin/" )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4")
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY LINK_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES "yes")
add_definitions(-D_UNICODE -D_USRDLL -DCORE_EXPORTS)
add_definitions("/Gm")

#Configuration de core.dll
add_library(

        core

        SHARED

    core/src/asserts.h
    core/src/errors.h
    core/src/filepath.h
    core/src/memory.h
    core/src/resources.h
    core/src/stdafx.h
    core/src/streams.h
    core/src/string.h
    core/src/system.h
    core/src/variants.h

    core/src/filepath.cpp
    core/src/main.cpp
    core/src/memory.cpp
    core/src/resources.cpp
    core/src/stdafx.cpp
    core/src/streams.cpp
    core/src/string.cpp
    core/src/system.cpp     
)
link_directories("/build/lib/")
target_link_libraries(core zlib)
```

But when i "configure" in CMake i've this warning now :

> CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:106
>   (if):   Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as
>   variables or   keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy
>   CMP0054" for policy   details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set
>   the policy and suppress this   warning.
>
> Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the
>   policy   is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior
>   will be used. Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:51
>   (project) This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to
>   suppress it.
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/CMakeFindBinUtils.cmake:33 (if):
>   Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables
>   or   keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for
>   policy   details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and
>   suppress this   warning.
>
> Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the
>   policy   is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior
>   will be used. Call Stack (most recent call first):   C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:162
>   (include)   CMakeLists.txt:51 (project) This warning is for project
>   developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Why ? I've not that before ?

Comment: You shouldn't link shared-object libs with static  libs, they should be static or shared to avoid problems. Then you could try to use [link_directories command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html) before using `target_link_libraries(core zlib)`

Comment: @fenix688 Ok. Sorry but I'm confused ... i've I have to add `link_directory("../external")` to my end of CMakeLists for Core ? and after `target_link_libraries(core zlib)` ? I've tried this but it's doesn't seems to work. Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: As you compile zlib, adding target_link_libraries(core zlib) will tell cmake to add a link dependency to core, so it will find the link directory by itself.

Comment: ok that's works, but i have to make one CMakeLists for the 2 projects. That's an error from me... sorry.